# React-Bootstrap: Label on the left side of checkbox

Tags: javascript, react-bootstrap

I use a checkbox from the React-Bootstrap library this way:

```
var checkBtn = ce(bootstrap.Input, {type: "checkbox", label: "Multiplied ",
checked: this.isChecked, id: "multBtn", onClick: this.onChange });
```

and I would like to have a label on the left side. How can I do this ?

Comment: I answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53118203/6608075) but realized it's already asked here too :)

Answer (score 1):

Had answered this in a different post before someone shared this question with me.

I used flex to solve this by changing the row direction.

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label title="">
        <input type="checkbox" value="">
        Did not perform
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  /*ie7 -- start*/
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}

div.checkbox > label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Output:

[image]

JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sx8mLj0o/8/)

You can find my original post/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53118203/6608075)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.

My workaround was to not use react-bootstrap (example using jsx):

```
<div className={'form-group'}>
  <label
    className={'control-label'}
    htmlFor={fieldName}
  >
    {fieldName + ':'}
  </label>
  <input
    type='checkbox'
    id={fieldName}
    name={fieldName}
    checked={fieldValue}
  />
</div>
```

I realize I have not answered your exact question.
Hopefully someone has a real answer.