# React-bootstrap: Reverse checkbox input so the label text comes first

Tags: css, react-bootstrap

I have a checkbox generated by react-bootstrap and it's rendered like a label containing input tag and label title.
I want to have it so that the label title comes first.

Checkbox from react-bootstrap:

```
<Checkbox
   checked={checkedStatus}
   onChange={(e) => this.handleToggle(e, checkBoxValue)}
>{title}</Checkbox>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label title="">
        <input type="checkbox" value="">
        Did not perform
    </label>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used flex to solve this by changing the row direction.

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label title="">
        <input type="checkbox" value="">
        Did not perform
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  /*ie7 -- start*/
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}

div.checkbox > label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Output:

[image]

JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sx8mLj0o/8/)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, and I had a similar problem that I solved using react-bootstrap Rows and Columns. Here's an example:

```
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";

const ExampleForm = () => {
//add your hooks, selectors, and logic
 return (
             <Form>
                <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-1">
                <Form.Label column sm="7">
                   Your title
                </Form.Label>
              <Col sm="4">
                <Form.Check
                  type="switch"
                  id="yourId"
                  checked={yourVariable}
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    dispatch(yourDispatchMethod(event.target.checked));
                  }}
                />
              </Col>
              </Form.Group>
            </Form>
            )

}
```

You can see more examples in the docs https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/forms/layout/#horizontal-form